# Creating a blog post organizer using a .JSON file

Tags: gatsby

I am using a static site generator (Gatsby) to create a website for a blog, and on the home page, I will organize the blog posts by type (a, b, c, all). In order to do this, there will be a group of 4 boxes, with Javascript that changes the div below to output pointers to blog posts based on whatever type is chosen.

My struggle is, how do I organize this data? My first guess was SQL, but that is for backend work (It's a static site, so there's no server). I could also use recursion to search each blog post by json tags. I will give each blog post a folder that contains a .json file with 4 metrics: a link to the md file, the name, the type(a,b,c), and the # of stars received(it's a review site). So basically, as I create new blog posts, I will populate a single .json file which will act as an array of blog posts, each holding the 4 metrics.

Would this be the best way to do this? When generating a list by a metric, I could cycle through the .JSON files, and display everything that matches.

(The best way I can describe how I want the generated pointers to look like is how the team members are displayed here: https://sosc.org.in/team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Gatsby you should use the strengths of Gatsby. My suggestion is to move away from JSON and use *markup* files and GraphQL instead. This way you use the best practices in the Gatsby ecosystem.

You can integrate your four categories by defining them in the frontmatter of your blog post's markup files.

There is official documentation about your specific problem right on the Gatsby project page: [Adding tag and categories to blog posts](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-tags-and-categories-to-blog-posts/)

Define your frontmatter in your blog post markup

```
---
title: "Category A!"
category: ["a"]
---

This is a category a post
```

Create a template file and GraphQL query as suggested in the [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-tags-and-categories-to-blog-posts/#make-a-tags-page-template-for-tagstag).

You're done. You categorize each blog post directly in the markup. Gatsby builds the page for you and assigns the right category.